# I want to upload and play video using video tag of HTML

Tags: php, html

I uploaded .mp4 and .webm video and trying to play these video using following code

```
<video width='407' height='240'   controls preload='auto' style="margin-top:10px;">
    <source src='http://www.long-alive-dev.com/web/video/<?php echo $row['demo_video_path']; ?>'>
</video>
```

But some .webm videos are playing and some videos are not playing, I don't understand why?
Please help me how can I play all types of video in my website?

Comment: Refer here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: What do you mean by some videos are playing and some are not playing? Are you talking about different formats of videos? OR some other .webm videos are not playing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the browser supports video format you are trying to play and also make sure that the paths are okay.
Do you have a link?

Comment: For eg.: http://www.long-alive-dev.com/web/health-course_detail.php?id=26 it will not work because the mp4 file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width='407' height='240' preload="auto" autoplay loop>
<source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="yourvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="yourvideo.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

try the following html5 code. You should provide at least two sources (recommended is three) for one video.it will work!!!